# How to ssh mini-kube or docker-desktop?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I want to ssh minikube/docker-desktop, but I cant. How can i do that?

```
NAME       STATUS   ROLES                  AGE     VERSION   INTERNAL-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
minikube   Ready    control-plane,master   4m47s   v1.20.2   192.168.49.2   <none>        Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS   4.19.121-linuxkit   docker://20.10.6

ssh minikube
ssh: Could not resolve hostname minikube: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I am learning K8s and able to ssh while working on K8s hands-on labs available online. I'd like t test some stuff on my local environment.

Comment: You should be able to run `kubectl`, `kustomize`, `helm`, _etc._ from the host environment on either Docker Desktop or Minikube without having shell access to the Kubernetes node environment.  Do you have a specific need for it?

Comment: I want to run kubeadm join command for mini-kube to join docker-desktop cluster. I guess it seems impossible from what I'm seeing. @DavidMaze

Comment: If you want a multi-"node" cluster, [kind supports that](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/configuration/#nodes) and also runs in a single Docker container.

Answer (score 1):

`minikube` is the node name within the Kubernetes API, not a hostname in this case. Minikube offers a wrapper [`minikube ssh`](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/ssh/) command to automate pulling the IP and whatnot. Docker Desktop does not offer an official way to get a shell in the VM as it's a single-purpose appliance and they want it in a known state, but you can fake it by running a super-superuser container like `docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid=host justincormack/nsenter1` to break out into the host namespaces.